# How could I get all items in current page that is showing?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

For the [offical example](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/hVXfT-JAEH7vP-Fkcw-QaNEHX47SQz0VjKA5eDPGLO0G9m67S3a3CpL-7zfbFmyrYEPKsjPfzDc_eXkZUS59Td-VPuqnhss5TNbGssQfM-sPrF36d0ZJr5SN0vhSOGX_ekWTpWDG_00t9UcqZsJ4fS7_ssiCw10JzqSFxe7oeQHCp3QmGAzRg-mR_rVgCYoMQcvC8gkTCOdK9ojVKSPQn3EZnxTXLC5RpvrzjMBAvTKNxhbum4Qe4BMMGI2ZvlLSov3iLr93FBbhWAed4tSUTPhc7pONacL2yR6V4Y75PvlICaohocbUNILOF0SDP-ptyjC91LKGoRhcvu_pjIkeGWO0_cghV9Yfp8mMlWHFh1AuwgruI-CDKBd71dsuFQdR26xUkPVEHUR_5KyCzy9r4KDzKV_BI53vq75rwFwM7j3h7-xh6QhhZ0n2Blzap-fN-ekxnJ2eZgQ6WyefTQY3Stl9bmKIlDBLir18TsKiheFCiAb1holC6iiG5bxgzDCUgktWDkW4HQfgbgB-Qr9Vn4heT6ZCwC8gBH6CsRon179TXLbIMeCnru0_aOy_y3Vr1QtXeTe0_cJD5abdLoghGeSFtYgZbPIIlpq_YtphppSAfAKhB45ntyYeULOYMBuUAx82SCDG5b6p1Wp3vZqZ4bVME6Zdfj5MbZdIaeSemy8tYJ7zrDmOmmMA1KxlBFNq_sGDHErsSiqwG-ILd99q57DNrqgVL_SN8upm82-ZvdEqcZsyBwc1DmGLvLEZXfLOkmmuYh5ZFwBpFynKwMuOSl0_Mke1LXylRLkSDXqRiI-6Xk3D1STf0Vg1nUdAnTqGLXFGsQEj9t3aLiuZzgSPIBI4b9toGzkoVYqWglut0iVsYM5sF-uJr6ypicME24E_rFnadHvle5PFrmvo7RSfXDYetcJs27Uz2CImoUKQ9vMer67HD3uNVer-t4qNdFBzmNeel40ZWY2l28e0hOw6sqQzVZP8UPZgvQbu0cymWsIPsnHMMziBjYszI92dWsEr87L_) of multiselection, if set display 50 row per page and click select all checkbox in title row, indeed all rows in table are selected. The problem is that I just want to select all the rows in current page, is any way to achieve it? I do not want to click every row manually.

Comment: Can you add more code?

Comment: You can create your own "select all in current page" button. If that is an option I can provide an example as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a demo for what you want to achieve: https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GaGQENEheDggnxaW

I removed the default "select all" checkbox from header and footer by using `MudTHeadRow` and `MudTFootRow` components and setting `IgnoreCheckbox` property to true. Also setting `CustomHeader` and `CustomFooter` property to true on the `MudTable` component itself.

Then I added a new `MudTh` that displays my own custom checkbox. When the checkbox is clicked I add or remove items to the `selectedItems1` HashSet based on the `CurrentPage` and `RowsPerPage` properties of the table.

```
<MudTable @ref="_tableRef" CustomHeader="true" CustomFooter="true" Items="@Elements" @bind-SelectedItems="selectedItems1" MultiSelection="true" Hover="@hover">
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTHeadRow IgnoreCheckbox="true">
            <MudTh>
                <MudCheckBox T="bool" Checked="IsSelectAllChecked" CheckedChanged="@Select"></MudCheckBox>
            </MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Number)">Nr</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh>Sign</MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Name)">Name</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Position)">Position</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
            <MudTh><MudTableSortLabel SortBy="new Func<Element, object>(x=>x.Molar)">Mass</MudTableSortLabel></MudTh>
        </MudTHeadRow>
    </HeaderContent>
    ...
    <FooterContent>
        <MudTFootRow IgnoreCheckbox="true">
            <MudTh>
                <MudCheckBox T="bool" Checked="IsSelectAllChecked" CheckedChanged="@Select"></MudCheckBox>
            </MudTh>
            <MudTd colspan="5">Select All</MudTd>
        </MudTFootRow>
    </FooterContent>
</MudTable>

<MudText Inline="true">Selected items: @(selectedItems1==null ? "" : string.Join(", ", selectedItems1.OrderBy(x=>x.Sign).Select(x=>x.Sign)))</MudText>

@code {
    private bool hover = true;
    private HashSet<Element> selectedItems1 = new HashSet<Element>();

    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();

    private MudTable<Element> _tableRef;

    private bool IsSelectAllChecked
    {
        get
        {
            var currentPage = _tableRef.CurrentPage;
            var rowsPerPage = _tableRef.RowsPerPage;
       
            var currentPageItems = _tableRef.FilteredItems.Skip(currentPage * rowsPerPage).Take(rowsPerPage);

            if (!selectedItems1.Any(x => currentPageItems.Any(y => x == y)))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
    }

    private void Select()
    {
        var currentPage = _tableRef.CurrentPage;
        var rowsPerPage = _tableRef.RowsPerPage;
       
        var currentPageItems = _tableRef.FilteredItems.Skip(currentPage * rowsPerPage).Take(rowsPerPage);

        if (!selectedItems1.Any(x => currentPageItems.Any(y => x == y)))
        {
            foreach(var item in currentPageItems)
            {
                selectedItems1.Add(item);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach(var item in currentPageItems)
            {
                selectedItems1.Remove(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I sort any column, this method fails. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Yes, I changed `Elements.Skip(currentPage * rowsPerPage).Take(rowsPerPage);` to `_tableRef.FilteredItems.Skip(currentPage * rowsPerPage).Take(rowsPerPage);` so that I get the filtered/sorted dataset from the table. Updated the demo.